# How to kill and start all sql server processes and services in task manager

Tags: sql-server, windows, process, windows-services, task

I am newbie about SQL Server and I want to kill all sql server processes and services in the task manager. Processes and services used by sql server, eat too much ram. When I don't use sql server they cause overload to windows and windows slows down. I want to kill all of them How can I do? In fact In the Computer Management I can stop services and processes one by one but it takes time. 
How can I stop all processes and services by just one click-one operation easily? 
How can I start all processes and services by just one click-one operation easily?
I used Windows 7.

Comment: Don't do this - use the services part of Computer Management.  It may take more time but it's much safer.

Comment: Also, you can set the max amount of RAM that SQL Server is allowed to use.  Set that to an appropriate number so you don't have to be starting and stopping services over and over.

Comment: How can I do this? max amaunt of ram?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to kill those processes with task manager.

Instead reconfigure your SQL Server to only use an appropriate amount of memory:

```
EXEC sys.sp_configure N'max server memory (MB)', N'200' --200 MB
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
```